# В чем разница между константой x и &xx?

Tags: c++, ссылки

В чем разница между константой x и &xx?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int x = 2;
    const int &xx = 3;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << xx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Зачем нужен `&`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Семантически эти два объявления различны

```
const int x = 2;
const int &xx = 2;
```

В первом случае объявляется константный объект, который инициализируется целочисленным литералом. Для него может даже не выделяться память, если не требуется обращение к памяти объекта. Компилятор может использовать значение этого константного объекта на этапе компиляции. Например,

```
const int x = 2;
int a[x];
```

Размер объявленного массива известен на этапе компиляции.

Что касается данного объявления

```
const int &xx = 2;
```

то здесь сначала создается временный объект для значения выражения `2`, и затем на этот временный объект определяется ссылка. Где разместится в памяти этот временный объект - это будет известно на этапе выполнения программы. Заметьте, что сам временный объект не является константным. Это просто результат вычисления выражения, состоящего из одного операнда - целочисленного литерала 2.

В связи с этим имеется различная реакция компиляторов на использование ссылки `xx`.

Так, например, компилятор MS VC 2016 Community не компилирует следующий фрагмент кода

```
const int &xx = 2;
int a[xx];
```

Сообщение об ошибке

> Ошибка    C2131   выражение не определяется константой    623

Как я думаю, MS VC++ 2016 Community в данном случае ориентируется на следующее положение стандарта C++ о константных выражениях (5.20 Constant expressionю, п. №2)

> - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type **that refers to a 
>     complete non-volatile const object** with a preceding
>     initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or

Обратите внимание, что указано, что должна иметь место ссылка на константный объект, в то время как временное выражение, которым инициализируется ссылка вышепоказанного фрагмента кода, является не константным. Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Этот же фрагмент кода успешно компилируется на www.ideone.com . Этот компилятор, по всей видимости, основывается на другом подпункте данного пункта стандарта C++

> - a non-volatile **glvalue of literal type** that refers to a non-volatile 
>     object **whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e**;

В этом подпункте ничего не говорится про константность литерального временного объекта. Достаточно, чтобы он имел литеральный тип.

Так что если покопаться в стандарте C++, а также посмотреть на поведение компиляторов, то различия будут явными.:)

Answer (score 6):

`const int &xx = 3;` - это ссылка на константное значение типа `int`. Откровенно говоря, рассказывать, что такое [ссылка в C++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28C%2B%2B%29), достаточно долго, поэтому позвольте ограничиться этим кратким ответом, отправив вас к соответствующей литературе.

Ссылка - это как бы псевдоним переменной, так сказать, альтернативное имя. В вашем конкретном случае поменять значение 3 просто так нельзя - это константа, поэтому и ссылка на это значение допустима только как на `const int`.

Comment: В чем разница между x и xx? Меня, например, интересует будут ли эти обе переменных хранится в памяти? Что можно сделать с x чего нельзя будет сделать с xx (и/или наоборот)?

Comment: @pank скорее всего никакой) компиляторы сейчас умные.

Comment: @pavel, люди все равно умнее) Если разницы ни какой, то зачем добавлять такую возможность в язык?

Comment: Что такое ссылка я понимаю. Сам часто ими пользуюсь.

Comment: Скорее всего ссылка будет (как и константная `x`) просто оптимизирована и выброшена. Если вы не соберетесь делать с ней чего-то интересного - типа получения адреса. В таком случае будет создана временная переменная в памяти, куда и положена эта тройка, например. Если нет - то, скорее всего, не будет ничего в памяти. Как не будет выделено в памяти место и для `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Разница на уровне машинного кода:

**gcc 6.x**

```
    // const int x = 2;
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2

    // const int &xx = 3;
    mov     eax, 3
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], eax
    lea     rax, [rbp-20]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
```

**gcc 4.5.x**

```
   // const int &xx = 3;
   mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 3
   lea     rax, [rbp-8]
   mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
```

Очевидно, что вторая инструкция [`const int &xx = 3;`] более дорогая, нежели первая. *Ваш кэп*.

Массив размером с x ? Пожалуйста. *Ни одной ассемблерной инструкции* - при условии, что мы его в дальнейшем *никак не используем*.

Массив размером с xx при условии, что мы его никак не используем. Пожалуйста.

```
    // gcc 6.x - int arr[xx];
    // комментарии излишне
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cdqe
    sub     rax, 1
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cdqe
    mov     r8, rax
    mov     r9d, 0
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cdqe
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, 0
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cdqe
    sal     rax, 2
    lea     rdx, [rax+3]
    mov     eax, 16
    sub     rax, 1
    add     rax, rdx
    mov     edi, 16
    mov     edx, 0
    div     rdi
    imul    rax, rax, 16
    sub     rsp, rax
    mov     rax, rsp
    add     rax, 3
    shr     rax, 2
    sal     rax, 2
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rax
```

Comment: Ну и добавлю, что все "вышесказанное машиной" - при отключенной оптимизации. Если оптимизация включена, как уже выше это обговаривалось @Harry, Vlad from Moscow - все будет вырезано.